# What does <?> mean

Tags: java, generics

I have created a generic class using the following code

```
public class MyBean<E> {

}
```

To create an object of that class I can use:

```
MyBean<String> m1 = new MyBean<String>();// valid --------------------statement 1
MyBean<?> m1 = new MyBean<String>(); // valid --------------------statement 2
```

but I get an error when I try to create an object using the following:

```
MyBean<?> m1 = new MyBean<?>();// invalid but why? --------------------statement 3
```

**Why is the statement 2 valid while the statement 3 is not. What is the meaning of `<?>`**

Comment: It is called a "wildcard". It is [covered in the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html), as well as in [lots of existing posts on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[generics]+wildcard&submit=search). Please do at least some research before posting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyBean<?>` means "a MyBean parameterized by a specific type, but I don't know which one. Because of the "I don't know which one", it makes sense in type declarations, but not in instantiations. You cannot create "something, but I don't know what".

Answer (score 0):

Basically, "?" means unknown. In statement two you DO know/declare (when you init) what kind of elements will your collection hold, ie a String. But on the 3rd statement you don't know anything so...

This link will surely be helpful:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 0):

MyBean can be used with any type as E. However, you do have to supply the type. MyBean supplies String to the type parameter E. MyBean does not supply a type parameter at all, so this is an error.

MyBean is a MyBean where you don't care what the type is. MyBean is also a MyBean, just like String is also an Object. Therefore, assigning any MyBean<> to MyBean works.

Answer (score 0):

`<?>` is a wildcard for generics. It is typically used with `extends` or `super` or both implying that the method/class the generic is applied to, extends or is a parent class of another object. The 3rd statement is invalid because you're saying you want to instantiate MyBean with an unknown type - at some point you need to bind a generic. It's like to trying to instantiate an Interface with and Interface.

If you want to learn more about generics I think this book is an excellent reference:
[Java Generics and Collections](http://books.google.com.mt/books?id=zaoK0Z2STlkC&lpg=PP1&dq=java%20generics%20and%20collections&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)